# How to display json data in html using javascript?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have the JSON file:

```
{
 "name": "sami",
"desig":"Employee"
 "location": "Pune", 
},
{
 "name": "joshaph",
"desig":"Employee"
 "location": "Delhi", 
},
{
 "name": "mani",
"desig":"Employee"
 "location": "Kolkatha", 
},
{
 "name": "Ravi",
"desig":"Manager"
 "location": "Pune", 
}
{
 "name": "Harthick",
"desig":"Manager"
 "location": "Delhi", 
}
```

And, I wrote the below code for retrieving json file,

```
 function fetchDataForJSON(callback) {
        var _url = "myURL";       
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/'/g, ''));
                callback(result);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
    }
function displayDetails(result){
var jsonObj = { ... }

}
```

I want to display it in a HTML page. And it should be categorized by desig. Any one can help me to write javascript code for displaying the details.

My result Should be displayed in a HTML page, under Employee category the 1st three members and under Manager category the last three members using javaScript.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Priya! A simple google search "Generate HTML from json response" will yield many helpful results. Try and solve the problem yourself first, and then come back here only when you get stuck. Post the code you've tried and tell us what's expected and not working. Visit the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info and also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think your .json syntax is incorrect - 
you have 
"name": "sami",
"desig":"Employee"
 "location": "Pune", 
},
but to my understanding it should be

"name": "sami",
"desig":"Employee",
 "location": "Pune"
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss commas!

```js
{
 "name": "sami",
"desig":"Employee",
 "location": "Pune", 
},
{
 "name": "joshaph",
"desig":"Employee",
 "location": "Delhi", 
},
{
 "name": "mani",
"desig":"Employee",
 "location": "Kolkatha", 
},
{
 "name": "Ravi",
"desig":"Manager",
 "location": "Pune", 
}
{
 "name": "Harthick",
"desig":"Manager",
 "location": "Delhi", 
}



success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var l = data[i];
               $("#....").val(l["name"]);
               $("#....").val(l["desig"]);
               $("#....").val(l["location"]);

                  }
            },
```